# how to execute query on simple vertical partitioning in sqlalchemy using python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i am trying to work with multiple database and schemas using simple vertical partitioning in sqlalchemy and python .

Have create two database engines and configured successfully to sessionmaker()

```
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(binds={BaseA:engine1, BaseB:engine2})
```

Able to get the required sql query  generated successfully

```
driverssql = session.query(drivers)
```

but when i execute the above query to fetch the requslts i get the follwing error  :

resultset=session.execute(driversql)

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session  (how can i associate the correct engine with execute statement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing here two variants:

1. You can create 2 sessionmakers here and use them separately according to an engine.
2. You can choose necessary engine when executing a query:

   ```
   engine1 = create_engine(first_db)
   engine2 = create_engine(second_db)
   session.execute(drivers, bind=engine1)
   ```

Comment: correct thats how did it .. there is also another nice way  i.e using custom vertical partioning ,in this scenario i dont have to bind any session but rather based on the model type passed to session ,query will be fired accordingly.https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/persistence_techniques.html#partitioning-strategies-e-g-multiple-database-backends-per-session